# Help with MLE regression

Tags: regression, estimation, maximum-likelihood

I have a data set containing two variables `x` and `y`. I want to estimate the parameters for a regression model.

The regression model is:

[image]

The maximum likelihood function that estimates the parameters is:

[image]

Here is a link to the data set: http://www.filedropper.com/data_14

Is there a way to estimate the parameters of this function? I've tried and spent many hours with R but can't get it to work. Matlab will do just fine as well.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is the model that this comes from? There may already be something that estimates it.

Comment: Hi Glen, I have added the model in the question now. Thanks!

Comment: You have part of it. What's the distribution on $\varepsilon$? Is it t-distributed?? If so, shouldn't $\nu$ appear on the right hand side of your log-likelihood?

Comment: Hi Glen, sorry for my unclear question. Yes, ε is t-distributed. In this case, ν=3. I've updated the log likelihood function. I would appreciate if you could help me out with this problem. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Perhaps you could tell us what is unclear after trying the examples on the `optim` help page?

Answer (score 2):

Your log-likelihood is wrong:

A t-density with location $\mu$, scale $\sigma$ and degrees of freedom $\nu$ is given by:

$f(t) = \frac{\Gamma(\frac{\nu+1}{2})} {\sqrt{\nu\pi}\,\sigma\,\Gamma(\frac{\nu}{2})} \left(1+\frac{(t-\mu)^2}{\nu\sigma^2} \right)^{-\frac{\nu+1}{2}}\!.$

setting $\nu=3$ and replacing $\sigma$ with $\sigma x^\lambda$.

$f(t) = \frac{2} {\sqrt{3}\pi\,\sigma x^\lambda\,} \left(1+\frac{(t-\mu)^2}{3\sigma^2x^{2\lambda}} \right)^{-2}\!.$

Writing the likelihood (using $y_i$ for $t$ and $\beta_0+\beta_1 x_i$ for $\mu$)

$$\cal{L} = \prod_{i=1}^{n} \frac{2} {\sqrt{3}\pi\,\sigma x^\lambda\,} \left(1+\frac{(y_i-\beta_0+\beta_1 x_i)^2}{3\sigma^2x^{2\lambda}} \right)^{-2}\!.$$

So the log-likelihood is

$$\cal{l} = k+ \sum_{i=1}^{n} -\log(\sigma x^\lambda\,) -2\log\left(1+\frac{(y_i-\beta_0+\beta_1 x_i)^2}{3\sigma^2x^{2\lambda}} \right)\!.$$

(though the $k$ may freely be dropped; it's still the log of the likelihood)

---

With pre-specified df, as here, MLE might be used*, but you may have to take some care with the heteroskedasticity parameter $\lambda$.

One possibility is to start with a robust line, estimate an approximate $\lambda$ from the residuals, and then cycle between estimating the parameters (e.g. possibly via the package `heavy`) of the line and the value of $\lambda$ (via univariate maximization).

Alternatively, you could maximize all the parameters simultaneously, for example, via something like `maxLik::maxLik` (again, starting with a robust line).

Note that if you use a function which doesn't have weights, you'd need to use a transformation to achieve the weighting (which in turn would require the ability 
to fit a regression without a constant term).

* see, for example, http://davegiles.blogspot.com.au/2013/12/more-on-student-t-regression-models.html

Comment: Wow! Thanks Glen!

Is there a easy way to estimate the parameters using for example R or Matlab or any other statistical software?